VBA scrape Yahoo Finance web page
For some years I've been using Excel/VBA to scrape stock prices from Yahoo. This has worked fine until a few days ago, when it looks like Yahoo have made some changes.
The core bit of VBA code is:
Set html = New HTMLDocument
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        
myUrl = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quotes/MSFT/view/v1"
Debug.Print myUrl
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", myUrl, False

oXMLHTTP.send
        
html.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText
Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML

Set mtbl = html.getElementsByTagName("Table")(0)
Set table_data = mtbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

I now get a Type Mismatch error at "Set mtbl...."
The reason appears to be the lack of table data in the HTML
<script>if(window!=window.top){document.write('<p>Content is currently unavailable.</p><img src="//geo.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757039&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&_R='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&err=404&err_url='+'https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Fuk.finance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquotes%2FMSFT%2Findex.html'+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');}else{window.location.replace('https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Fuk.finance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquotes%2FMSFT%2Findex.html');}</script><noscript>&lt;META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&amp;err_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Fuk.finance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquotes%2FMSFT%2Findex.html'"&gt;</noscript><script>if(window!=window.top){document.write('<p>Content is currently unavailable.</p><img src="//geo.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757039&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&_R='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&err=404&err_url='+'https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Fuk.finance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%

2Fquotes%2FMSFT%2Findex.html'+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');}else{window.location.replace('https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Fuk.finance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquotes%2FMSFT%2Findex.html');}<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Fuk.finance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquotes%2FMSFT%2Findex.html'">
My suspicion is that Yahoo have blocked web scraping and only allow viewing data in a browser.
Any ideas?

You may have a look on an similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79147756/17172829
